# Nested try-except for raising exceptions in Python

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm wondering if the nested "try/except/else" structure (in the main function) is a good practice in Python. Right now, the structure is not that deep but I could continue on and on with additional conditions in the "else" part. Is there a better way to implement this ?

My code written in `main.py`:

```
import logging
import traceback
import flask
from google.cloud import firestore


class DocumentDoesNotExist(Exception):
    """
    Exception raised when there is no document corresponding to a given token in Firestore/collectionA nor
    Firestore/collectionB.
    """


class DocumentExistElsewhere(Exception):
    """
    Exception raised when there is no document corresponding to a given token in Firestore/collectionA but there is
    one in Firestore/collectionB.
    """


def get_patient_info(token):
    db = firestore.Client()
    document = db.collection(u'collectionA').document(token).get()

    if document.exists:
        return document.to_dict()
    else:
        document = db.collection(u'collectionB').document(token).get()
        if document.exists:
            raise DocumentExistElsewhere
        else:
            raise DocumentDoesNotExist


app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/<request>")
def main(request: flask.Request):
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, GET',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age': '9600'
    }

    allowed_origins = [
        "http://localhost:5000"
    ]

    origin = flask.request.headers.get('Origin') or flask.request.headers.get('origin')
    if origin in allowed_origins:
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin

    if flask.request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        return '', 204, headers

    if flask.request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            request_json = flask.request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)  # Returns None if fails.
            token = request_json['token']
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
            return "Cannot retrieve token from request", 400, headers
        else:
            try:
                info = get_patient_info(token)
            except DocumentDoesNotExist:
                return "Token provided does not correspond to any document in Firestore/collectionA nor in " \
                       "collectionB.", 404, headers
            except DocumentExistElsewhere:
                return "Token provided corresponds to a document in Firestore/collectionB but none in " \
                        "Firestore/collectionA.", 404, headers
            else:
                return info, 200, headers


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

You can run the Flask app like this `python3 main.py` and then testing with a curl  `curl -H "Origin: http://localhost:5000" -X GET -d '{"token":"06sr1"}' -i http://localhost:5000/test`

Also, if you can see any problem with my implementation I'm open to any tips :)

Comment: I'm curious to hear how you expect the code to be used in the future. In particular I have 2 questions. Are you going to have many collections or will it be limited to these 2? What should a user do on a DocumentExistElsewhere response?

Comment: @IvoMerchiers only 2 collections. But generally speaking it could expand. When DocumentExistElsewhere, I actually send a message to the front to display something.

Comment: Would you then expect the user to retry the query but for collectionB or is the access model more complicated?

Comment: Every time the user do the query, it has to check collectionA before collectionB

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `try ... except ... else ...` construct works as follows.

```py
try:
    print("Code protected by the try-statement")
except AnException:
    print("Exception handling code - not protected by try-statement")
else:
    print("No exception occurred code - not protected by try-statement")

print("Common code executed whether or not an exception occurred.")
```

Now let's add in a bit of your exception handling code...

```py
try:
    print("Code protected by the try-statement")
except AnException:
    print("Exception handling code - not protected by try-statement")
    return
else:
    print("No exception occurred code - not protected by try-statement")

print("Common code executed whether or not an exception occurred ...")
print("except if an exception occurs, the code returns and won't get here!")
```

It should become obvious that the only way to get to the last two `print()` statements is if the `print()` statement in the `else:` clause is executed.  If an exception occurs, the function exits via the `return` statement.  Therefore, the `else:` clause is unnecessary.

```py
try:
    print("Code protected by the try-statement")
except AnException:
    print("Exception handling code - not protected by try-statement")
    return

print("No exception occurred code - not protected by try-statement")
print("Common code executed whether or not an exception occurred ...")
print("except if an exception occurs, the code returns and won't get here!")
```

This means there is no need to have nested `try ... except ... else ...` statements.  Simply omit the `else:` clauses.

```py
        try:
            request_json = flask.request.get_json(force=True, silent=True)  # Returns None if fails.
            token = request_json['token']
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
            return "Cannot retrieve token from request", 400, headers

        # No else-clause here

        try:
            info = get_patient_info(token)
        except DocumentDoesNotExist:
            return "Token provided does not correspond to any document in Firestore/collectionA nor in " \
                   "collectionB.", 404, headers
        except DocumentExistElsewhere:
            return "Token provided corresponds to a document in Firestore/collectionB but none in " \
                   "Firestore/collectionA.", 404, headers

        # No else-clause here either

        return info, 200, headers
```